# java fx jvm crash

Tags: java, linux, jvm, javafx, java-7

I have a swing application and inside i added a JFXpanel from javafx2 jdk1.7_17 (also tried 1.7_15). i do create the JFXpanel in EDT and add it on swing tabbed pane, then add the scene to the FXPanel in javaFX thread as shown in the doc. If i run the application once everything is fine, if i stop the application and run it again the jvm crashes saying Problematic Frame libdbus. After closing the application no matter how many times i try the jvm will crash complaining about dbus usually but not always:

```
JRE version: 7.0_17-b02
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  [libc.so.6+0x12fbd6]Java Result: 134
```

Sometimes i get this:

```
 GConf-WARNING **: Got Disconnected from DBus.
```

If i restart the pc it runs ok the first time again and then if i close / re-run it keeps crashing at start up. I am running fedora 18 and i believe it maybe OS related since java FX is using native libs.

```
FXPanelJob fxPanelJob = new FXPanelJob(fxPanel);
tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
tabbedPane.addTab("table", fxPanel);
Platform.runLater(fxPanelJob);

private class FXPanelJob implements Runnable {

    private JFXPanel fxPanel;
    private volatile boolean done = false;

    public FXPanelJob(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        this.fxPanel = fxPanel;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        initFX(fxPanel);
        done = true;
    }

    private void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        // This method is invoked on the JavaFX thread
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 300, 200);
        TableView<ReportRaw> table = new Table();
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(table);
        VBox.setVgrow(table, Priority.ALWAYS);
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);
    }
}
```

Since the first time is running i just guessed that might be a problem with shutting down the javafx on application exit. On windowClosing event i have:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){ public void run(){
         Platform.exit();
});
```

## Update:

It turns out its not a java fx problem, i switched to JDK 6 and everything is fine. I think it is specific to OS problem. Using jdk 7 without java fx could still trigger jvm crash.

if anyone knows what might be causing the jvm to crash i would appreciate.
Thank you in advance

## Update 2

found a similar post, it seems to have been solved but i am not sure: 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1697231&page=3
use this for jvm arguement -XX:-UseCompressedOops. i'll post it as an answer when i make sure its not crashing anymore.

## Update 3

Couldn't solve it i commented out my javafx code as a solution. I believe its EDT related but i cant guarantee. it seems to be occuring several lines after the JavaFx panel is added on swing app. Not always at the same line. If removed everything works, so i guess its still an immature project.

Comment: Could you please file a bug on javafx-jira.kenai.com or bugs.sun.com for this issue?

Comment: Will do tonight, sorry for the delay. I'll post the link back here as well in case anyone needs it. Thank you.

Comment: started a bug in jira as requested. Thank you for the -1. Have fun.  https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/JMY-216

Comment: can you add crash log?

Comment: I used to have a crash log saved but unfortunately none replied here or in jira so i deleted all my javaFX code and decided its unstable and i wont use it. I should be able to reproduce it if i go back in the repository but i guess it will be a waste of my time at work. It seemed to be random it would crash after adding the java fx panel on a swing app.